# SSH ramdisk tool not running

Tags: java, ssh, jar

First thing I installed Java jdk and jre

Then I installed a file called ssh_rd_rev04b.jar

I tried to open the jar file but it didn't run

I double clicked it,
I made a .bat file and typed java -jar filename didn't work too, tried other things but didn't work as well .

Please help .

Comment: What does happen when you execute java -jar ssh...jar ? How should we guess what's wrong with an arbitrary jar file?

Comment: @StefanHegny that's the problem bro nothing happens it just do not open, no error, nothing